# Cancel AlertDialog in onPause method of Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, cancel-button

following is my code for AlertDialog,

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
alertDialog.setTitle("GPS settings");
alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");
alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
       }
 });

alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
       dialog.cancel();
       }
   });
alertDialog.show();

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
 // I want dialog to be dismissed here

}
```

Its working fine but what i want is to dismiss the dialog in onPause method of Activity,
how can i achieve it ?

Comment: use dialog.dismiss() function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in `onPause`

```
alertDialogforGPS.dismiss();
```

**EDIT:**

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder;

builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(WelcomeActivity.this).setTitle("Title")
.setMessage("Message")
.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
        //your code
    }
})
.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

And in `onPause`

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: alertDialog.dismiss(); is not available

Comment: @RajeshSuthar is your `alertDialog` object  global ?

Comment: @SilentKiller : yes it is global

Comment: @MysticMagic : when i am removing .Builder from AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext); it gives me an error

Comment: @RajeshSuthar what is your actual dialog object on which you call show method? You need to use that `dialog` instance for dismiss as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65337/discussion-between-rajesh-suthar-and-mysticmagic).

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

Declare global variable..

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog;
```

Define and Access it when you need it.

```
alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
alertDialog.setTitle("GPS settings");
alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");
alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
       dialog.dismiss(); // NOTE : dismiss dialog before moving to other activity.. it will prevent causing exception... 
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
       }
 });

alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
       dialog.dismiss();
       }
   });
```

accessing variable in other methods..

```
@Override
protected void onPause(){
    //checking for null variable
    if(alertDialog != null)
        alertDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: i want it only within onPause method

Comment: then make a public variable.. so u can access it in onPause() method too

Comment: Make sure the view is `showing`: `if (this.alertDialog != null && this.alertDialog.isShowing())`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to make the `AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog` a member of your class. Like:

```
private AlertDialog.Builder mAlertDialog;
```

Then, at the point where you define your alert dialog, you use this member:

```
mAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
mAlertDialog.setTitle("GPS settings");
mAlertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");
mAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }
});

mAlertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});
mAlertDialog.show();
```

And then in the `onPause()` method, you can dismiss the dialog.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (mAlertDialog != null) {
        mAlertDialog.dismiss();
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```